# Title page and abstract on right page with blank page in between

Tags: titles, koma-script, double-sided, scrbook, blank-page

My thesis is a `twopage` `srcbook` komascript document and has a titlepage, followed by an abstract and then the table of contents. All these "Chapters" should appear as right (odd, recto) pages. The problem is, that the title page always appears on a left (even, verso) page.

The document should follow this format: **(title,right)**, **(blank, left)**, (abstract, right), (blank, left), (TOC, beginning on right page), ... with every chapter beginning on a right page.

Instead, it looks like this: **(title, left)**, (abstract, right), (blank, left), (TOC, beginning on right page), ... and every new Chapter on a right page.

So the 'simple' solution would be a single blank page after the title, but no matter what I try, I can not insert a blank page by hand. 
I have already tried `\newpage`, `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage`. I have set the `openright` option in the documentclass.

I am using the pdfLaTeX compiler from Overleaf with pretty much standard settings, if that helps. It would be possible for me to switch to `srcreprt` if something does not work in this document class.

```
\documentclass[ngerman, twoside, openright, fontsize=12pt, toc=bibliography]{scrbook}

\usepackage{Defs}

\begin{document}

\titlehead{\centering\includesvg[width= 7cm]{...}}
\publishers{
...\\
...}
\subject{...}
\title{\Large{\textbf{...}}}
\author{...}
\date{...}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\chapter*{Zusammenfassung}
...

\vspace{0.25\textheight}

\section*{\LARGE{Abstract}}
...

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Einleitung}
\label{chap:einleitung}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See page 288 in the (English) manual regarding all the different `\clearpage` alternative in scrbook. Also, you may set the option `titlepage=firstiscover` so scrbook does not handle the titlepage as the first page of the book. Read what the author writes regarding  this at page 65.

> The third choice, titlepage=firstiscover not only activates title pages but also prints
>   the first title page of \maketitle, i. e. either the half-title or the main title, as a cover page. Any other setting of the titlepage option will cancel this setting. The margins of the coverpage are given by \coverpagetopmargin, \coverpageleftmargin, \coverpagerightmargin, and \coverpagebottommargin. The defaults of these depend on the lengths of \topmargin and \evensidemargin and can be changed with \renewcommand.

```
\documentclass[ngerman, twoside, openright, fontsize=12pt, demo, titlepage=firstiscover,%                                  %%  NB!
toc=bibliography]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\titlehead{\centering\includegraphics[width= 7cm]{demo}}
\publishers{
...\\
...}
\subject{...}
\title{\Large{\textbf{...}}}
\author{...}
\date{...}
\maketitle
\cleardoubleoddemptypage   % NB! This command or one of the other clearpage-commands
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\chapter*{Zusammenfassung}
...

\vspace{0.25\textheight}

\section*{\LARGE{Abstract}}
...

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Einleitung}
\label{chap:einleitung}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Heschoscho In addition, I recommend using the `\addsec` or `\addchap` command to ad _ad hoc_ section command as you abstract. The document class `scrrprt` already has this command (as `scrartcl`, but not `scrbook` because abstract in a book normally is a separate chapter at the end of the book, see manual pages 71--72.